# Mixed up output

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a function or program that outputs the following lines `<input>` time:

```
Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.
Big Brown Fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro.
```

**EDIT**: It's "*B* rown *F* ox" not "brown fox".

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the program with the shortest bytecount wins!

Comment: Can we ignore the capitalization?

Comment: I think in most languages the code to mix up the characters is larger than embedding the strings directly.

Comment: I can't even work out what algorithm is applied to get the third sentence.

Comment: @Peter: The first word is the odd characters of the original words, the second one is the even characters.

Comment: @Joey: surely not in Perl, Golfscript, J and maybe even others.

Comment: @Eelvex, then shouldn't the last one be Bbfgoxn Irow?

Comment: @Peter: It's up to the length of the smallest word but it would be fine if you want to implement it like "Bbfgoxn Irow".

Comment: @Peter @Eelvex ... careful ... that sounds like cursing :D

Comment: A 'code-challenge' should be challenging.

Comment: @boothby, I believe codegolfing this it's challenging enough.

Comment: `Bbfgox Iro` isn't even a permutation....................

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Take 1st character of each word: Bbf. 3rd character of each word: gox. There is no 5th character of "Big" and "Fox" so the first word is "Bbfgox". 2nd character of each word: "Iro". ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ruby - 84 chars

```
"Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.
Big brown fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro."*n
```

Answer (score 5):

### vim - 82 strokes

```
oHello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.
Big brown fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro.<ESC>
```

Type the number of repeats you want before entering this.

Answer (score 2):

**Python <s>110</s> 105 Characters**

```
exec"print'Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.\\nBig brown fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro.';"*input()
```

Comment: you can take off 5 characters by using one print and \\n to end the line

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript - 100 characters

```
while(n--)print('Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.\nBig brown fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro.')
```

Answer (score 1):

## D: 127 Characters

```
auto f(int n){return join(repeat("Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.\nBig brown fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro.",n),"\n");}
```

More Legibly:

```
auto f(int n)
{
    return join(repeat("Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.\nBig brown fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro.", n), "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell: 95

```
"Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.`nBig Brown Fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro.`n"*(read-host)
```

Read-Host prompts the user for input, then the string is multiplied by that value and printed. This will have an extra newline at the end, but I don't see that as a constraint in the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>761</s> 724 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_input_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_heap_at_0][S N
S _Duplicate][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
N
_Discard_top][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate_input][N
T   T   T   N
_Jump_to_Label_EXIT_if_negative][S S S N
_Push_0][S S T  T   S T T   S S T   N
_Push_-89_\n][S S T T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-53_.][S S S T    T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S S T T   T   T   N
_Push_15_r][S S T   T   T   S T S N
_Push_-26_I][S S T  T   S S S S T   T   N
_Push_-67_space][S S S T    S T S T N
_Push_21_x][S S S T T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S S T S S N
_Push_4_g][S S S T  T   N
_Push_3_f][S S T    T   N
_Push_1_b][S S T    T   S S S S T   N
_Push_-33_B][S T    S S T   T   S N
_Copy_6th_space][S S T  T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-53_.][S S T  T   N
_Push_1_b][S S S T  T   S N
_Push_6_i][S S T    T   T   T   S S N
_Push_-28_G][S T    S S T   S S N
_Copy_4th_space][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1_b][S S S T T   T   T   N
_Push_15_r][S S S T T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S S T S T S S N
_Push_20_w][S S T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-21_N][S T    S S T   S T N
_Copy_5th_space][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3_f][S S S T  T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S T   T   S T T   N
_Push_-11_X][S T    S S T   T   N
_Copy_3rd_space][S S T  T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-53_.][S S S T    S T S T N
_Push_21_x][S S S T T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S T   T   T   T   S T N
_Push_-29_F][S T    S S T   S S N
_Copy_4th_space][S S S T    S T T   N
_Push_11_n][S S S T S T S S N
_Push_20_w][S S S T T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S S T T   T   T   N
_Push_15_r][S S T   T   S S S S T   N
_Push_-33_B][S T    S S T   S T N
_Copy_5th_space][S S S T    S S N
_Push_4_g][S S S T  T   S N
_Push_6_i][S T  S S T   T   N
_Copy_3rd_B][S S T  T   S T T   S S T   N
_Push_-89_\n][S S T T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-53_.][S S S T    S S T   N
_Push_9_l][S N
S _Duplicate_9_l][S S S T   T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S T   T   T   T   T   S N
_Push_-30_E][S T    S S T   S S T   N
_Copy_9th_space][S S S T    N
_Push_1_d][S T  S S T   T   N
_Copy_3rd_o][S S S T    T   T   T   N
_Push_15_r][S S S T S S T   N
_Push_9_l][S S S T  S T S S N
_Push_20_w][S S T   T   T   S T T   N
_Push_-27_H][S T    S S T   T   S N
_Copy_6th_space][S S T  T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-53_.][S S S T    S T N
_Push_5_h][S S S T  S N
_Push_2_e][S S S T  S S T   N
_Push_9_l][S N
S _Duplicate_9_l][S S T T   S T S S N
_Push_-20_O][S T    S S T   T   S N
_Copy_6th_space][S S S T    S T S S N
_Push_20_w][S S S T T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S S T T   T   T   N
_Push_15_r][S S S T S S T   N
_Push_9_l][S S T    T   T   T   T   T   N
_Push_-31_D][S T    S S T   S T N
_Copy_5th_space][S S T  T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-53_.][S S S T    N
_Push_1_d][S S S T  S S T   N
_Push_9_l][S S S T  T   T   T   N
_Push_15_r][S S S T T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S T   T   T   S S N
_Push_-12_W][S T    S S T   T   S N
_Copy_6th_space][S S S T    T   S S N
_Push_12_o][S S S T S S T   N
_Push_9_l][S N
S _Duplicate_9_l][S S S T   S N
_Push_2_e][S S T    T   T   S T T   N
_Push_-27_H][N
S S S N_Create_Label_PRINTER
][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S N_Jump_to_Label_LOOP_if_0
][S S S T   T   S S S T T   N_Push_99
][T S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINTER]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dVJBDgIxCDwPr@APvsgYE72ZaOLzK0xLod11m1AWBoYh/T6en/v7db3dW1NVsQOBf/TdmPWYGf@zjBCoBoFH6ZpPj6F@IzMdzShzB3DUyDREi2cw6qMKUdqjrEX0iCS2/pgjR9eYoOCoaHBuqraJyYvCqyja9HQRRVE01akkOU@XyojoOgCm8A7KLrkAVawLKBL1oLFfKyNG7Sz5K1FzcKAqrSTLVNjWvxPl85jyiwoZD1YS7WEMGqZau/wA) (containing the raw spaces, tabs and new-lines).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
integer i = input_as_integer
Start LOOP
  i = i-1
  if i is negative:
    EXIT
  Call function PRINT

function PRINT
  Print "Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.\n
         Big Brown Fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro.\n
         "
  Go to the next iteration of LOOP
```

**Some things I did to golf it:**

- `SNS` (Duplicate) is used for repeated characters (`ll`)
- 99 is subtracted from every ASCII-value, which we'll add in the PRINT function to reduce loads of bytes. In Whitespace an integer/character is formed by using `SS` (Stack Manipulation: Push Number) + `S` or `T` (Positive or Negative) + some `T` / `S` (Binary representation of the number where `T=1` and `S=0`) + `N`. So having lower binary values and adding the 99 in the `PRINT` function is shorter than using the large binary values directly.
- Since creating the number for a space is 11 bytes (`SSTTSSSSTTN`), I copied the spaces from the last occurrences to the top of the stack instead. For example, after the first space is created in `\n.orI xogfbB`, I then use `STSSTTSN` (copy 6th to top) instead to copy the previous space. The largest distant between two spaces is 9, and since `STSSTSSTN` (copy 9th to top) is still 2 bytes shorter than `SSTTSSSSTTN` (create space) I've done this for all spaces to save bytes.
- I did something similar as with the copying of spaces above for every character that has a distance of 3 or less. This applies to the `B` in `Big B`  and the `o` in `od Eo` (Note: The distance between both `b` in `b. Bb` is also three, but creating the number for `b` (`SSTTN`) is actually shorter than copying the 3rd value to the top of the stack (`STSSTTN`).)

Answer (score 0):

### Game Maker Language, 107

```
repeat argument0{return "Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.#Big Brown Fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro."}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 121 bytes

```java
n->{for(;n-->0;System.out.println("Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.\nBig Brown Fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro."));}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY@9TsNAEIR7nmKU6lz4REN1IoXFT1JgihQgAcXZPptLNrvW@RIHRX52c5BIu8XMaLXfbO3R5tI73ja7uSY7DHixns83gOfoQmtrh/JPAkfxDWqVfHBmkjWlTTNEG32NEox7zJwvz60EZTjPl7dm8zNEt9dyiLoP6ZRYLVaOSPAmgRqNBwoy4pXIfWusxqQaPAqR/uTCdyhSyniSk8a7tChHCRWefaVRVG0nJ6yD6EWWmWk2F5z@UFHCuVL9Q@9TJbWJ6X/38WWzSx3Wtbq79pjmXw)

```java
n->{           // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  for(;n-->0;  //  Loop `n` times
    System.out.println("Hello World. Dlrow Olleh. Hwlrod Eoll.\n
                        Big Brown Fox. Xof Nworb Gib. Bbfgox Iro."));}
               //   And print this text + a trailing new-line that many times
```

Comment: Bleh, why bump a challenge like this?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I'm just looking for old `[tag:string]` solutions to practice programming in Whitespace, and noticed this didn't had a Java answer yet either.. Also, golfing languages might be better suited to utilize the repeated characters in the challenge (although it's more likely they just use a text encryption for the entire text, so I understand the duplicated vote..)

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I've dupe-hammered it.

Comment: I mostly wanted to discuss: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8143/what-should-we-do-with-old-challenges-no-longer-on-topic but Dennis closed my meta because it already exists apparently. Odd how this predates that challenge though. Technically we should be closing the rickroll one.

Comment: "_Odd how this predates that challenge though. Technically we should be closing the rickroll one._" We don't always close the newer one as a dupe. Sometimes an older one is closed instead if the newer one is much better specified (if the author of the older challenge agrees). [Here is a recent example of that, with Martin's reasoning and relevant meta-post at the top.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157403/compute-the-kolakoski-sequence)

Comment: Oh, I agree, I wonder if there's a meta post on that.